# Unable to draw a pixel or oval circle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to draw pixel circle but need help with few issues:

1. When the width and height of the grid are not even, it should draw an oval shape but it's not and it leaves empty cells along the grid edge
2. If I increase the size to a higher number, it fills the whole screen and off screen so just wondering if one can constraint it to a fixed grid size

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // Get the grid container element and input elements
    const gridContainer = document.getElementById("grid-container");
    const widthInput = document.getElementById("width");
    const heightInput = document.getElementById("height");

    // Function to generate the grid layout
    function generateGridLayout(width, height) {
        // Clear any existing grid
        gridContainer.innerHTML = "";

        // Set the grid container's grid-template-columns based on width
        gridContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${width}, 24px)`;

        // Create the grid blocks
        for (let i = 0; i < height * width; i++) {
            const block = document.createElement("div");
            block.classList.add("grid-block");
            gridContainer.appendChild(block);
        }


 
    // Calculate the center of the grid
    const centerX = (width % 2 === 0) ? (width / 2) * 24 : ((width - 1) / 2 + 0.5) * 24;
    const centerY = (height % 2 === 0) ? (height / 2) * 24 : ((height - 1) / 2 + 0.5) * 24;

    // Determine the radius of the circle
    const radius = Math.min(centerX, centerY);

    // Create and position the circle
    const circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.classList.add("grid-circle");
    circle.style.width = `${2 * radius}px`;
    circle.style.height = `${2 * radius}px`;
    circle.style.left = `${centerX - radius}px`;
    circle.style.top = `${centerY - radius}px`;
    gridContainer.appendChild(circle);

    // Color the grid blocks that are closest to the circle's edge
    const gridBlocks = gridContainer.querySelectorAll('.grid-block');
    gridBlocks.forEach(block => {
        const center = { x: block.offsetLeft + 12, y: block.offsetTop + 12 };
        const distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(center.x - centerX, 2) + Math.pow(center.y - centerY, 2));

        if (distance < radius && distance > radius - 24) {
            block.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"; // Change this to your desired color
        }
    });

    console.log(`Center of the grid: (${centerX / 24}, ${centerY / 24})`);
    console.log(`Radius of the circle: ${radius}`);
}       


    // Event listener for changes in the width input
    widthInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
        const newWidth = parseInt(widthInput.value, 10);
        const currentHeight = parseInt(heightInput.value, 10);
        generateGridLayout(newWidth, currentHeight);
    });

    // Event listener for changes in the height input
    heightInput.addEventListener("input", function() {
        const currentWidth = parseInt(widthInput.value, 10);
        const newHeight = parseInt(heightInput.value, 10);
        generateGridLayout(currentWidth, newHeight);
    });

    // Generate the grid layout with the default values
    const defaultWidth = parseInt(widthInput.value, 10);
    const defaultHeight = parseInt(heightInput.value, 10);
    generateGridLayout(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
});
```

```css
#grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 24px);
  /*gap: 0.5px;*/
  position: relative;
}

.grid-block {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
}

.grid-oval {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid-center-dot {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="row mt-5">
        <div class="col-md-4"><label for="width">Width:</label><input id="width" class="form-control" type="number" min="3" max="200" value="10" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><label for="height">Height:</label><input id="height" class="form-control" type="number" min="3" max="200" value="10" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><label for="thickness">Thickness:</label><input id="thickness" class="form-control" type="number" min="1" max="50" value="1" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-12"><label for="scaler">Zoom:</label><input id="scaler" class="form-control-range" type="range" min="1" max="5" value="1" /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid-container"></div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-4"><button id="downloadPNG" class="btn btn-primary">Download as PNG</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><button id="downloadJPG" class="btn btn-primary">Download as JPG</button></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><button id="downloadSVG" class="btn btn-primary">Download as SVG</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```